# What's the best way of emulating try/catch with golang

Tags: go

What's the best way of emulating a try/catch in golang  . Consider the psuedo-code in java to execute a bunch of sql

```java
db.Attach(dbFile)
try {
   db.Exec(sql1);
   db.Exec(sql2);
   db.Exec(sql3);
} catch (SQLExecption e) {
    throw new Error("sql error in executing " + dbFile + " ", e);
}
```

to do this in golang, I would have to do something like

```golang
db.Attach(dbFile)
var err error
if err = db.Exec(sql1); err != nil {
   log.Panic(fmt.Sprintf("error in attaching db %s error : %s", dbFile, err))
}
if err = db.Exec(sql2); err != nil {
   log.Panic(fmt.Sprintf("error in attaching db %s error : %s", dbFile, err))
}
if err = db.Exec(sql3); err != nil {
   log.Panic(fmt.Sprintf("error in attaching db %s error : %s", dbFile, err))
}
```

I can shorten it to something like

```
db.Attach(dbFile)
db.MustExec(sql1)
db.MustExec(sql2)
db.MustExec(sql3)
```

But I won't be able to get information about the attached db in the error message. How do I achieve the effect of try/catch without being too verbose, short of putting the SQL statements in a splice and looping through it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possible to use the https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Errorf `fmt.Errorf(...)` function to create an error. It is also possible to create custom errors and handle that error.

Comment: https://go.dev/blog/defer-panic-and-recover may be what you are looking for.

Comment: If you really want to condense the error handling, you may create helper functions that don't return the error but store it if one occurs, and if there's a previous error, the op will be a no-op. For an example, see my lib [`github.com/icza/bitio`](https://github.com/icza/bitio). In the [doc](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/icza/bitio) you can see there are matching `TryXXX()` methods of the `Reader` and `Writer`, so you can write code and check error later.

Comment: Shorten it to `db.Exec(sql1, sql2, sql3)`, have the func be defined as `Exec(qq ...querytype)`, range over `qq` then exec each `q`, exit loop on first fail.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at typical (C++, Python, Java..) exceptions, there are two aspects to the exception handling:

- The "regular" value is not returned. Instead, the function gives back an exception.
- The control flow takes a different path.

You can do these things separately in Go.

For the returnvalue vs. exception as function result, the typical Go idiom is to return a tuple. If you return e.g. a `string` in languages with exceptions, in Go you return `string, error` instead. If your function succeeds (the `return` equivalent), you `return "some string", nil` in Go. In case of failure, you return `nil, some_error` instead. The `fmt.Errorf()` function helps creating these `error` instances. Also, you guessed it, the exception class is replaced with Go's `error`.

For the control flow, there is nothing inherent that you could use. The idiom is to check the returned tuple whether its `error` element is not `nil`. If so, you just return to the calling function, forwarding the returned error. If you want to return a more specific `error` implementation (equivalent to exception wrapping/chaining), you just create it with the existing `error`.

This may seem annoying, because it only works well with `return` and not locally, but remember that you can always use e.g. `defer` to define epilogue code and also that you can use local functions ("closures") to structure your code.

Answer (score 0):

In the Go language, you can catch panics like catching exceptions.
Although it's not recommended to replace the manual error handling, but it's possible.

```golang
func catchme() {
    panic("oh no!")
}

func main() {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            log.Println("panic occurred:", err)
        }
    }()

    catchme()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I wrote a library to that avail : https://gitlab.com/reda.bourial/catch

Here is how you can catch errors :

```golang
panicked,err:=Panic(func(){
  // You SQL queries go here
})
``
```

Comment: i don't understand your question can you rephrase it ?

Comment: Yes, it is intented to be imported with a `.` and provide an easy way to not repeat error management in each unit test.

Comment: good remark thank you i've updated my answer

Comment: Removing the unnecessary use of goroutines may improve the package performance. See https://go.dev/play/p/59WaFszoHxK for an example of how to return a value from recover without using a goroutine.